# How to display JinternalFrame in jDisktopPane, but that DisktopPane contains GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I not able to getting the proper JinternalFrame. In my application in main JFrame I have one disktopPane that contains GridLayout.

When I call JInternalFrame by click on button I am getting that internalFrame, but that fix to a particular Grid box only, and I am not able to maximize the InternalFrame.

How can I solve the probleam?

below is my GUI:

[image]

I am doing Code through NetBeans.

How Can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a jdesktoppane. Use a normal JFrame with a JPanel with your components and the gridbaglayout.
For the windows floating above the main JFrame use new JFrame's with setAlwaysOnTop(true) and make sure they have your main JFrame as root.

Comment: without  jdesktoppane ,how can i display jInternalFrame in main Jframe ? Could please provide some code for this.

Comment: Don't use jInternalFrame. Use JFrame with setAlwaysOnTop(true).
jInternalFrame is for use with jdesktoppane